# What does a reserved keyword mean in SQL when it's not applicable to the current statement?

Tags: sql, parsing, grammar

What exactly does it mean when a keyword is reserved in SQL? For example, if we use the word `GRANT` which is not applicable outside of admin statements. What exactly does it mean then that the keyword is reserved, for example can I do any of the following:

- Use the word as a database, schema, table, or column name?
- Use the word as a function, procedure, trigger, or index name?
- Use the word as an alias, for example within a `SELECT` statement?
- Use the word as a key in a JSON (or STRUCT/RECORD) key?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get a single database-agnostic answer. You can get a definite answer for each specific database.

Comment: @GSerg sure you can use any database here. Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved word have to be escaped if really want to use them outside their scope.

It is usually dioscouraged as you need to add **all the time** the escape characters.

Single quotes don't escape the reserved the but make them to strings, so the databse will not produce an error

double quotes can be escape characters like in postgres or strings like in MySQL. in both cases you wouldn't get an error message

You get an error message because the parser checks for keywords like the re4served words and chekc if the syntax is correct, which is never the case when you use reserved words.